# Git: Failed to sync this branch

Tags: git, github

Закомитил изменения, но не могу синхронизироваться с GitHub, выдает ошибку

> Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage

Подскажите, что с этим делать? Раньше без проблем комитил изменения гораздо больших размеров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На гитхабе есть [лимит на размер файла](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) - 100Mb

Все, что больше 100Mb, нужно хранить с использованием [Git Large File Storage (Git LFS)](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/). Он поддерживается гитхабом, так что вам нужно просто скачать и настроить его для своего локального репозитория.

Кстати, ссылка на LFS и на на инструкцию по настройке есть прямо в сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: Удивительно, насколько люди способны игнорировать сообщения об ошибках.